# A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:)

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, httprequest, redirect

I am getting a strange issue on production server, while on all other environments(DEV,UAT) are working fine.

When i trace log file there is only one error what i found:

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: HttpException 
    Exception message: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context)
```

Could someone please suggest me, what is missing over there.

Comment: What data caused this?

Comment: not sure, while navigating to home page getting this error

Comment: Did you debug it to see where it's being thrown?

Comment: it's on production server, can't debug there. Found this error on log file.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this because of built-in request validation. You can get by this by removing ':' in your configuration file:

```
> <system.web>
>     <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="<,>,*,%,&,:,\,?" /> </system.web>
```

Here's the [detailed article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx) on the same.

Comment: are you using WebForms or MVC ?

Comment: this is on WebForms.

Comment: try this: <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="<,>,*,%,&,\,?" requestValidationMode="2.0" />

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you have something ending in this `/tel:` in your request path that it will cause the error.

Like for instance

```
<a href="tel:123456">Call ME!</a>
```

I found you can work around this by removing the `href` link and to this instead

```
<div onclick="window.open('tel:123456');"  
     style="cursor: pointer;">Call ME!</div>
```

Comment: I'm getting the same, but you haven't posted a solution :)